# Midori not starting up in fresh install

Tags: 11.10, midori

I'm running a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10 running Gnome Shell, everything working as it should.

I just installed Midori from regular Ubuntu repositories using Synaptic Package Manager, but when l attempt to launch it, despite the appearance of the Midori icon and the "whirl" in the top panel, the browser does not start. Switching GUI does not change the effect.

As requested, starting Midori from the terminal generates the following output:

```
giulio@giulio-laptop:~$ midori midori: symbol lookup error: midori: undefined symbol: webkit_web_view_get_selected_text
```

Comment: what version of libwebkit are you running?  Have you installed any other PPAs - the reason for the question is your error is mentioned in this bug report: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=743382

Comment: I just found out I'm using a version from a WebUpd8 PPA I use for Gnome Shell extensions. I did not realise libwebkit was going to be upgraded too. It's now very late here, tomorrow I will try to contact the PPA maintainer to see if he has a proposed solution and I will also force the package version to the Ubuntu-provided one, then I'll report back and eventually close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>(converted comment into answer)</sub>

```
midori midori: symbol lookup error: midori: undefined symbol: webkit_web_view_get_selected_text
```

This error message was reported in [this RedHat](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=743382) bug-report.

Specifically it mentions an incompatibility between a similar version of Midori used in Oneiric with an updated (v1.6) of libwebkit.  I note that Oneiric uses version (v1.4).

In your comments you mentioned you are using the WebUpd8 PPA that upgrades libwebkit.  Obviously you now have a conflict between package versions.

Fixes are available for midori - but you'll need to compile from GIT to obtain these - as yet, the Midori PPA doesnt have this fix.

Alternatively consider `ppa-purge` the offending PPA.  Down-grading your libwebkit may fix your Midori issue - but most probably will break whatever PPA application that required the updated version of libwebkit.

Comment: For future reference: reverting the libwebkit packages to the Oneiric-provided version did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Use these to remove the old midori package and install the new package from the `midori` ppa:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge midori
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:midori/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install midori
```

You can  also use the updated webkit package from the [unstable webkit ppa](https://launchpad.net/~webkit-team/+archive/unstable).

Comment: Thank you, I will consider this option but I'd rather find a different solution first than adding a PPA, as in my experience these have created problems when upgrading.

Comment: You can try only the 1st and 3rd steps (total removal and reinstall)

Comment: Has an alternative you can try the updated webkit version from [here](https://launchpad.net/~webkit-team/+archive/ppa).

Comment: that webupd8 webkit is the same version as in oneiric... :)

Comment: :( you dont miss any details do you! :P

Comment: @fossfreedom Ha! fixed! (Not really but he can give it a go no?)